# SQL query TO JPQL one

Tags: sql, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to convert this sql query :

```
SELECT *
    FROM event
    WHERE idEvent IN (SELECT idEventfk FROM userevent WHERE absence='1');
```

Into a JPQL one :

```
SELECT e FROM Event e where e.idEvent
IN (SELECT ue.idEventfk FROM userevent ue WHERE ue.absence='1'
```

but it's returning `null` as result. Any idea about the mistake ?

Comment: without providing the entities? or saying what SQL was generated when you did the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.* FROM Event e where e.idEvent
IN (SELECT ue.idEventfk FROM userevent ue WHERE ue.absence='1')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have related entity's object present in the Event entity, then you can join them to get the required result:

```
select e from Event e join e.userevent ue where ue.absence = '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT e FROM Event e 
where exists 
  (SELECT ue FROM userevent ue WHERE e.idEvent = ue.idEventfk and ue.absence='1')
```